# Do you put a ferrite bead on both the positive voltage and GND trace?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, dc, emi-filtering, ferrite-bead

I'm designing some basic DC power filtering for a very simple PCB. Do ferrite beads go on BOTH the positive voltage trace AND the GND trace, or should GND be completely free?

[image: ferrite circuit]

Comment: This is a system question: we can't even guess without knowledge of the rest of the system and the nature of the EMI you're attempting to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

You generally want each connection to the ground node to be as low impedance as possible to every other ground node. Ferrite beads are inductors, so you're introducing an inductance between two points that should be the same voltage. You should probably remove the ferrite bead on ground.

Comment: There are good reasons to put impedance in series with connectors, but we cannot determine whether that is the case based on present information.